# Error with installing .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows 10

Tags: .net, sdk, windows-10, matlab-compiler

I am trying to install SDK 7.1 complier for MATLAB2010bSP2 and it requires .NET Framework 4.0 for complete installation. But .NET Framework 4.0 installation says its already included along with Operating System or a higher version 4.8 is installed.

I am trying to downgrade the .NET Framework so that complete installation of SDK 7.1 Complier can be done. Below is the image of the .NET Framework 4.0 Installation setup.
Any leads on how to deal with this would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZOjA.jpg)